# Порядок сортировки базы и системный

Tags: 1с, windows, сортировка

При старте 1С под Windows7 (1С77 полная конф укр) выдается сообщение "порядок сортировки отличается от системного" и не запускается 1С. Менял вроде языковые настройки и стандарты с русских на украинские - не помогает. Под Windows XP при украинских стандартах все работает Если кто знает, помогите на украинском форуме никого и 1Сlancer.ru не работает сайт. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2009/10/1s-predpriyatie-77-osobennosti-raboty-v-windows-7-vista.html) почитайте, возможно поможет. Не хотелось бы нагло передрать весь текст статьи, посему лишь да наиболее правильное решение с точки зрения автора, с оговоркой, оно будет работать либо в XP, либо в Seven (и там и там это решение, к сожалению, не работает):

> **Конфигуратор - Администрирование -**
> **Кодовая страница ИБ** и в самом низу
> выпадающего списка выбираем + **Текущая системная установка**